# c# and javascript regex issue

Tags: c#

The same regex is working on c# but not working on javascript.
javascript example --`https://jsfiddle.net/x7cuatz1/` 
c# example -- `https://dotnetfiddle.net/HTxKaT`

--> I am working on a project where all the validations(regex) are stored in SQL, and it's used by asp .net MVC application, now I want to use them into my react app.

it's working when I am modifying the regex, but I don't want to modify them.

**Edit**

I know about the regex engine in different - different languages, but there is approx 1000+ regex in our system and we can't afford to change them.
changing(making them compatible with both js and c) them is the last option for us.

Comment: Your escaping is wrong.

Comment: @SLaks I know, but I don't want to change it, because it's working in C#.

Comment: `it's working when I am modifying the regex, but I don't want to modify them` Not all regex engines work the same way. You're going to have to provide different patterns for the .NET engine than you would for the javascript one.

Comment: There's no question in this question. A list of things you want and do not want is not a question. Can you ask a *specific question that has an answer*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's regular expression support is actually somewhat rudimentary compared to other platforms. Some differences that are significant for your particular pattern:

- JavaScript doesn't support `\p` tokens (e.g. `\p{L}` or `\p{M}`)
- The character classes `\w` will match `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Lm}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]` in Dot Net, but will only match `[A-Za-z0-9_]` in JavaScript. In truth, however, this doesn't really matter because your pattern has `[\w\W…]` which in effect means *any character*.
- JavaScript doesn't support character class subtraction, but given the point I mentioned above `[\w\W-[…]]` can be simplified to `[^…]` to get to a pattern that works on both platforms.

A full list of what's supported in these two engines can be found on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

If you need to have one pattern that will work on the client and the server, you'll have to limit your pattern to only use constructs that are fully supported in both environments. This particular pattern can be simplified to:

```
^[^`;<=>@\[\]_{|}¦\\]{1,5}$
```

You might also have a look at the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) project, particularly the [Unicode addon](http://xregexp.com/plugins/). This will make things like `\p{L}` and `\w` work more consistently across the two platforms, but I still doubt you'll get 100% compatibility between your client and server code even with this tool.